# How use systemd-nspawn with --network-veth and --port ( -n and -p)?

Tags: linux, containers, systemd-nspawn

I run;

```
systemd-nspawn -n -p 80:80 -bD /path/to/httpd-container
```

In the container, httpd works. However, accessing from host,  it dose not access. In addition, the below works without network options;

```
systemd-nspawn -bD /path/to/httpd-container
```

What do I need to use option `-n`, `--network-veth` and `-p`, `--port`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

Same question here; in order to help others reproduce from scratch:

### Preparation

pull a mundane image from the internet

```
machinectl pull-raw --verify=no https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/25/CloudImages/x86_64/images/Fedora-Cloud-Base-25-1.3.x86_64.raw.xz
```

### Test 1

Run a server inside a container with no networking option

```
systemd-nspawn -M Fedora-Cloud-Base-25-1.3.x86_64.raw nc -l localhost 10000
```

in another window

```
echo hello | nc localhost 10000
```

works

### Test 2

Enabling private networking and port mapping, so that host port 10000 is mapped to container port 20000

```
systemd-nspawn -M Fedora-Cloud-Base-25-1.3.x86_64.raw --private-network -p 10000:20000 nc -l localhost 20000
```

but then

```
echo hello | nc localhost 10000
```

results in

```
Ncat: Connection refused.
```

### Why it's wrong

I would almost have expected exactly opposite results; in any case the second test is the use case that I'd like to get to work. I really need my containers to be network-isolated, and need port redirection in any case as all the containers run their service on the same port, which need to be redirected to a range of ports on the host side.

### What I've tried

Adding the option `--network-interface=eno1` (my public interface) to the mix has not helped

### What puzzles me

My host runs fedora25 with selinux disabled; still I can see these messages when firing the container, which I take it are unrelated, but are they ?

```
mount(/tmp/nspawn-root-tR1Tr0/sys/fs/selinux) failed, ignoring: No such file or directory
mount(/tmp/nspawn-root-tR1Tr0/sys/fs/selinux) failed, ignoring: Invalid argument
```

Comment: for the record, I have contributed a related github issue at https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6106 with similar content